# Rails db migrations mariadb and transactions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions, mariadb

By default rails and rake will use transactions when performing database migrations, if the database supports them. Mysql does not and so using the mysql2 adapter, transactions are not used. I'm using MariaDB as a drop in replacement for mysql, and it does support transactions. Is there a way to tell rake/rails to use transactions? Do I need to find or write my own adapter for MariaDB?

Comment: Both MySQL and MariaDB support transactions.  But you need to specify `ENGINE=InnoDB`, not `MyISAM`.